# How can I run the EICAR test file?

Tags: anti-virus, malware

There exists an EICAR anti-malware test file. It is basically just a short string and looks like this:

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

You can read more about it on [the EICAR website](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html). That linked page states that:

> The file is a legitimate DOS program, and produces sensible results
>   when run (it prints the message
>   "EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!").

My question is how can I run it? First I have to disable my anti malware utility so that I can save it to a file. After that I'm not sure what to do with it in order to run it.

Obviously its not going to work as an exe file since it doesn't start with 'MZ', but I can't get it to work as a com file either. I get "This version of {filename} is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running". My flavor of windows (Win7 Pro) should be able to run both 32 and 64 bit programs.

I understand that its intended use is to verify that anti malware software is working as expected, but I want to understand what the file itself does.

Comment: It's a 16-bit program, which your 64-bit version of Windows can't handle.

Answer (score 2):

Dos programs are 16-bit programs and cannot be run in 64-bit Windows natively at all. However, because there are a plethora of 16-bit games that people desire to run on Windows (from the DOS era) there exists a solution.

DOSBOX

Get DOSBOX up and running, (Mount a folder containing this file) and try running it within DOSBOX. I don't know if it's supposed to be run as COM or not, but try it all within DOSBOX and you should have success!